# How can I add a red error message for wrong input in the form in rail3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

So in rails, if any of the input is not valid, the page returns back to the input page and red errors will show up next to that input_text or textarea.
For example, 
<%
    validates_presence_of :email
%>
It will say the error at the top, and the email input text turns into red.

However, when I separately made a valid checking statement in a model, for example,
<%
    def valid_email?
        TMail::Address.parse(self.email)
        rescue
            errors.add("Please type in the correct email address.")
    end
%>
It will say the error at the top, but the input_text itself does not turn into red.

How can I manually set the input text to be turn into red??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
self.errors.add(:email, "Please type in the correct email address.")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
self.errors.messages[:email] = ["your error message"]
```